# How to set background image in PdfPCell in iText?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, document, pdfptable

I am currently using iText to generate PDF reports. I want to set a medium size image as a background in `PdfPCell` instead of using background color. Is this possible?

Comment: Please note that the `com.lowagie.*` package have been removed [a long time ago](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/50) from iText. You should not use such an old, unsupported version of that library.

Comment: It is possible, but as Alexis already indicated, you're using my name in your code which means that you should really upgrade to a more recent version of iText.

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example on how to do this with iText 5.5.1 [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ImageBackground). You need to create your own implementation of the  `PdfPCellEvent` interface, for instance:

```
class ImageBackgroundEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

    protected Image image;

    public ImageBackgroundEvent(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
            image.scaleAbsolute(position);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
            cb.addImage(image);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }
```

Then you need to create an instance of this event and declare it to the cell that needs this background:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG1);
cell.setCellEvent(new ImageBackgroundEvent(image));
```

This code was tested with the most recent version of iText and the result looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/imagebackground.pdf). You're using a version of iText with my name (Lowagie) in the package names (com.lowagie). This means that this sample may or may not work. We don't know and we won't test as the version you're using [has been declared EOL years ago. It is no longer supported.](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq)